# Clarification required on GMainContext and GMainLoop

Tags: glib, gobject

I am getting started with Glib, GmainContext, GMainLoop, GObject, etc. but am trying to understand the underlying implementation. I understand select, poll, epoll, the main event loop, etc and have written C programs (without Glib) which use them.

I am trying to co-relate GmainContext and GMainLoop to these primitives. Is GmainContext a loop as described in a few articles such as [this](https://tecnocode.co.uk/2014/03/27/what-is-gmaincontext/)? If so, how does it differ from GMainLoop? It appears that GmainContext is where most of the work is done.

Please clarify and/or provide references.

Comment: You’re essentially asking for a full explanation of how GMainContext and GMainLoop work, which is a bit outside the scope of stackoverflow. If you have more specific questions, I can potentially help, but you’ve already found the right articles. If you’re interested in how the code works more specifically, I suggest you actually read the code. To answer your concrete question, though: `GMainContext` is an abstraction around the FD handling for `poll()`. `GMainLoop` is a thread-safe `while (condition) … ` loop around it.

Comment: @PhilipWithnall You are right about the nature of my question and apologies. That said, the statements in the article: _"What is GMainContext? It’s a generalised implementation of an event loop,"__  and   __"At its core, GMainContext is just a poll() loop"__ makes it difficult to distinguish it from GMainLoop which is the usual while(condition) event loop, as I understood and u clarified. Thanks  U r right... there is no alternative to looking at the source code to truly understand.

Comment: @PhilipWithnall I think that the reference manual links for Glib and GIO on https://developer.gnome.org/references are broken. One can navigate and get to them indirectly from previous versions link. They work directly for GObject.  Just FYI.

Comment: @PhilipWithnall GMainContext is a data structure (struct _GMainContext) so the statement that it is a loop is misleading for a novice like me.

Comment: The documentation links being broken is a known problem, and is being worked on. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: GMainContext is a data structure which maintains some additional state around calls to poll(). Its APIs implement various stages of the poll() call cycle. g_main_context_iteration() is the body of the loop.

Comment: @PhilipWithnall  I am trying to learn Glib and GObject with the ultimate goal of learning libnice and GStreamer. Want to get the overall basic concepts clear before I dive into coding... Thanks for the help.

Comment: I do understand it's discouraged but couldn't stop myself from writing it. Thanks @asinix for asking the question. It's immensely helpful.